# Snooze function in alarm android

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I have created multiple alarm app. This alarm triggers on time everything works fine. While saving alarm I have add, weekly, daily and once feature, user will be able to set alarm accordingly.

On alarm trigger. I have snooze and cancel.

Snooze: I have added 10 minutes from current time to snooze
cancel: Just finish() - so that it can trigger the next day or Next week (accordingly)

When click on Snooze button all the alarm that I have set gets cancelled and only one get triggered after 10 minutes. This is something strange? Not sure where the problem is?

Here is what I tried in my Snoozeactivity (which gets called from broadcast receiver)

OnCreate of SnoozeActivity:

I am getting hour, mins, am/pm and adding 10 mins to it and setting the alarm.

```
if (ampm.equalsIgnoreCase("AM"))
  {
    ampm = "0";
        }
 else if (ampm.equalsIgnoreCase("PM"))
  {
    ampm = "1";
    }
        Calendar alarmCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.valueOf(hours));
        alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.valueOf(mins));
        alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Integer.valueOf(ampm));

        currenttime = alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis() + 600000;

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(SnoozeActivity.this, AlarmReciever.class);
        intent.putExtra("keyValue", key);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmSnooze.this, 0, intent, 0);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, currenttime, pi); 
        finish();
```

Is it because of PendingIntent (Flag?)

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that you're using the same ID for your regular alarm.  In this line...

> PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmSnooze.this, **0**, intent, 0);

...the first "0" in bold is the alarm ID.  If you're using "0" for your other alarm ID then your snooze code will overwrite that previous alarm.  Change the "0" to "1" (or any other unused value) for the snooze alarm and you should be fine!